# Selenium no such element exception, unable to locate in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm unable to use selenium in this code.By ID,Name or xpath using both.PLease tell me way to do so. how to use this in selenium . getting this error:-OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name =""]"}

````
<input id="sys_display.incident.location" name="sys_display.incident.location" aria-labelledby="label.incident.location" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="" ac_columns="u_location_code" ac_order_by="u_location_code" data-type="ac_reference_input" data-completer="AJAXTableCompleter" data-dependent="" data-dependent-value="" data-ref-qual="" data-ref="incident.location" data-ref-key="null" data-ref-dynamic="false" data-name="location" data-table="cmn_location" class="form-control element_reference_input" style="; width:240px;" spellcheck="false" onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.incident.location'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXTableCompleter(gel('sys_display.incident.location'), 'incident.location', '', ''); e.ac.onFocus();})" aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="AC.incident.location" aria-expanded="false" title="" aria-invalid="false">```
````

Comment: Please show the code. Without seeing what you have written, it is difficult to inspect the issue

Comment: here is the code .Please tell me what to be used and using which method to find the element in web application

Comment: This element has a tag, id, name, aria-label, etc., many attributes. So it should usually work. Can you share the website link to investigate on the DOM?

Comment: Can you please suggest some of it other then id and name. Website cannot be provided. As its not public yet

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to assess without actually inspecting the DOM, but since you mentioned that the website cannot be shared; with the given input in the query, here are some of the possibilities:
Please note that these may work or may not, as I have no way to test them. They are just built using your line in the query.

There could be another possibility that your component maybe sitting in an iframe. Please check that also. If it is, then you have to first switch to iframe, and then traverse this element.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sys_display.incident.location")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "sys_display.incident.location")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-labelledby='label.incident.location']")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='label.incident.location']")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='Search']")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='search']")
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@ac_columns='u_location_code']")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[role='combobox']")
```